# Why does eclipse create a class file in bin directory as soon as I create a java file in it?

Tags: eclipse

As soon as I create a java file in eclipse it creates the corresponding class file in the bin directory which I assume is because eclipse compiles any java file as soon as it is created?Am I right?And later does it compile any java project  again when I run it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `Project > Build Automatically` checked then Eclipse compiles your Java code as you go.

The code is not compiled again when you Run the program.

Comment: If I donot have build automatically option set does eclipse compile the project when we run it?

Comment: Yes it does a build before the Run

Answer (score 1):

You are right for the first part (eg: a `*.class` in the `bin` directory).

Eclipse does incremental compilation (eg: almost like *compile as you type*).

For the second part, I don't understand your question.

Comment: Ah incremental compilation! So by the time we run any eclipse java project, all the compilation task is finished is it so?

Answer (score 1):

It will happen in case **Build Automatically** option is checked (Menu-->Project-->Build Automatically). If you uncheck that option .class file will not be created when you save java file.